# I have a question about deadlocks on MySQL 8.0

Tags: mysql, database, innodb, deadlock

I'm using MySQL version `8.0.26` and transaction isolation is the default value `REPEATABLE-READ`.

Here is my table

```
create table test
(
    id          int auto_increment primary key,
    a           varchar(256) null,
    b           int null,
    c           int null,
    create_time timestamp default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP null,
    constraint uni_key unique (a, b, c)
);
```

Here is my deadlock scenario

| Session A | Session B | Session C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| begin; | begin; | begin; |
| insert ignore into test(a,b,c) values ('a',1,1); |  |  |
| Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec) |  |  |
|  | insert ignore into test(a,b,c) values ('a',1,1); | insert ignore into test(a,b,c) values ('a',1,1); |
|  | (blocked) | (blocked) |
| commit; |  |  |
|  | Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (7.55 sec) | Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (3.83 sec) |
|  |  |  |
|  | insert ignore into test(a,b,c)values('a',2,1); |  |
|  | (blocked) |  |
|  |  | insert ignore into test(a,b,c)values('a',2,1); |
|  | Query OK, 1 row affected (5.29 sec) | ERROR 1213 (40001): Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction |

I wonder why SessionB second insert will be blocked and why a deadlock occurs.

After deadlock, I use `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS \G`.

```
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2023-04-25 09:42:47 140135040808704
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 15578, ACTIVE 21 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 6 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 3 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 33, OS thread handle 140135392589568, query id 775 localhost root update
insert ignore into test(a,b,c)values('a',2,1)

*** (1) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 23 page no 4 n bits 72 index PRIMARY of table `manager`.`test` trx id 15578 lock_mode X
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;


*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 23 page no 4 n bits 72 index PRIMARY of table `manager`.`test` trx id 15578 lock_mode X insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;


*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 15579, ACTIVE 17 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 5 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 3 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 35, OS thread handle 140135392884480, query id 776 localhost root update
insert ignore into test(a,b,c)values('a',2,1)

*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 23 page no 4 n bits 72 index PRIMARY of table `manager`.`test` trx id 15579 lock_mode X
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;


*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 23 page no 4 n bits 72 index PRIMARY of table `manager`.`test` trx id 15579 lock_mode X insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (2)
```

If switch transaction isolation to RC  there is no dead-lock error.

I read the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking.html) but couldn't find a description for my scenario maybe I missed it.

## Update

I notice that this should be locking the current primary key to infinity but don't know why.

I looked up more information, It turns out that this might have something to do with pseudo-record.

The problem can be simply described as:

| Session A | Session B |
| --- | --- |
| insert ignore into test(a,b,c) values ('a',1,1); |  |
| begin; |  |
| insert ignore into test(a,b,c) values ('a',1,1); |  |
| Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.01 sec) | begin; |
|  | insert ignore into test(a,b,c) values ('a',1,1); |
|  | (blocked) |

and this time I see the data locks

```
> SELECT ENGINE_LOCK_ID as Lock_Id,
       ENGINE_TRANSACTION_ID as Trx_id, 
       OBJECT_NAME as `Table`,
       INDEX_NAME as `Index`, 
       LOCK_DATA as Data, 
       LOCK_MODE as Mode,
       LOCK_STATUS as Status,
       LOCK_TYPE as Type         
FROM performance_schema.data_locks;

+-----------------------------------------+--------+-------+---------+------------------------+------+---------+--------+
| Lock_Id                                 | Trx_id | Table | Index   | Data                   | Mode | Status  | Type   |
+-----------------------------------------+--------+-------+---------+------------------------+------+---------+--------+
| 140135522398208:1088:140135454819312    |  15656 | test  | NULL    | NULL                   | IX   | GRANTED | TABLE  |
| 140135522398208:23:5:27:140135454816400 |  15656 | test  | uni_key | 'a', 1, 1, 64          | S    | GRANTED | RECORD |
| 140135522398208:23:4:1:140135454817088  |  15656 | test  | PRIMARY | supremum pseudo-record | X    | GRANTED | RECORD |
+-----------------------------------------+--------+-------+---------+------------------------+------+---------+--------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

**so, the question will update to why there is a supremum pseudo-record occurs.**